# HTTParty request failing when setting headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I'm trying to upload a video to Vimeo. If I leave the headers empty and only pass the authorization token, it works fine. When I set the content length header the request is failing. Any ideas on how to properly create a request header?

The method I created for adding headers:

```
 def add_header(key, value)
   @headers[key.to_sym] = value
 end
```

The way I'm adding content-type header:

```
add_header('content-type','video/mp4')
```

When I comment out this line, the requests works fine, but it's required by Vimeo. When debugging, I found the has to HTTParty is formed like this, could this be causing the error:

```
{:headers=>{:authorization=>"Bearer xxxxx", :"Content-Type"=>"video/mp4", :"Content-Length"=>"54047"}
```

Comment: Do `@headers.to_json` while executing the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strings for headers keys instead of symbols. Remove `.to_sym` in `add_header` method

```
def add_header(key, value)
  @headers[key] = value
end
```

Comment: glad to help :)